# How to test google pay 3d secure flow

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, braintree, google-pay

Currently i am using braintree to integrate google pay. I have done all the code changes required. I have already joined test card group provided by google for testing.
But i need to test flow for 3d secure cards. Currently all the cards in test card suit are not 3d secure. How can i test this flow ? When i try to add cards from braintree or other sources, it gives me error with code OR-CCSEH-21.

Tried joining test card group by google. But it does not include any card with 3d secure.

I am using custom integration for google pay in braintree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to trigger 3DS for non tokenized Google Pay cards if you use their [custom integration](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/google-pay/client-side/javascript/v3/#get-the-sdk) you can follow [this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/client-side/javascript/v3/#using-3d-secure-with-google-pay). The following code triggers a 3DS challenge flow for me:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
var paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
  environment: 'TEST'
});

var threeDSecure;

braintree.client.create(
  {
    authorization: 'abcd1234' // <-- needs a client token! (Tokenization keys can't be used)
  },
  function (clientErr, clientInstance) {
    braintree.googlePayment.create(
      {
        client: clientInstance,
        googlePayVersion: 2,
        googleMerchantId: 'merchant-id-from-google', // Optional in sandbox; if set in sandbox, this value must be a valid production Google Merchant ID
      },
      function (googlePaymentErr, googlePaymentInstance) {
        braintree.threeDSecure.create(
          {
            version: 2, // Will use 3DS2 whenever possible
            client: clientInstance,
          },
          function (threeDSecureErr, threeDSecureInstance) {
            if (threeDSecureErr) {
              // Handle error in 3D Secure component creation
              return;
            }
            threeDSecure = threeDSecureInstance;
          }
        );

        paymentsClient
          .isReadyToPay({
            apiVersion: 2,
            apiVersionMinor: 0,
            allowedPaymentMethods:
              googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest()
                .allowedPaymentMethods,
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response.result) {
              button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var paymentDataRequest =
                  googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest({
                    transactionInfo: {
                      currencyCode: 'USD',
                      totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                      totalPrice: '100.00', // Your amount
                    },
                  });

                var cardPaymentMethod =
                  paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods[0];
                cardPaymentMethod.parameters.billingAddressRequired = true;
                cardPaymentMethod.parameters.billingAddressParameters = {
                  format: 'FULL',
                  phoneNumberRequired: true,
                };

                paymentsClient
                  .loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
                  .then(function (paymentData) {
                    googlePaymentInstance.parseResponse(
                      paymentData,
                      function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                          // handle error
                          console.log(err);
                        }

                        // 3DS challenge when not NT
                        if (result.details.isNetworkTokenized === false) {
                          threeDSecure.verifyCard(
                            {
                              amount: '100.00',
                              nonce: result.nonce,
                              bin: result.details.bin,
                              onLookupComplete: (data, next) => {
                                // use 'data' here, then call 'next()'
                                next();
                              },
                            },
                            function (err, response) {
                              if (err) {
                                // handle error
                                return;
                              }
                              var lsShifted = response.liabilityShifted;
                              var lsPossible = response.liabilityShiftPossible;

                              // 3DS 'enriched' Google Pay nonce
                              //to send to your server for the actual authorization
                              console.log(response.nonce);
                            }
                          );
                        }
                      }
                    );
                  })
                  .catch(function (err) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(err);
                  });
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            // handle error
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: sorry, i should i mentioned, i am using custom integration, not drop in.
Also how to test this in dev sandbox env ?

Comment: what kind of custom integration? can you link to braintree docs?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/google-pay/client-side/javascript/v3/#get-the-sdk

Comment: @BenBeckman Thanks. I updated my code. Please take another look.

Comment: @BenBeckman did my sample code work for you?

Comment: yes it worked, just for anyone who faces this issue, try adding 3dsecure flow, and after that when you try payment on dev env, it will ask you for otp. if using braintree, below doc  helps https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/client-side/javascript/v3